# Graph Theory Software

Tags: graph-theory, math-software

I am looking for software to draw graphs with edges and nodes, show colorings, etc. Where can I find such software?

Comment: Thank you for that link. What do I do when I post a duplicate?

Comment: Umm... nothing, really.  If you want to contest that it is not a duplicate, you would post a comment explaining why.  If you agree that it is a duplicate, then you don't worry about it, and users with the privileges to handle it take care of it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica does it fine (see GraphPlot and GraphPlot3D)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of programming, then igraph library is a good choice. It is written in C but can be accessed from R and Python.

http://igraph.sourceforge.net/documentation.html

This tutorial might be useful

http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: And to connect the two answers posted here: now [igraph can be accessed directly form Mathematica](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM), combining the power of the two systems!